# How to get Route component to Render properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm Unable to Route to a specific component (WeatherDetails) in my application

I tried rendering the said component normally (outside a route), and it displayed perfectly but incorporating it in , nothing displays and also i get no error message. Here the code

Root component

```
import WeatherDetail from './WeatherDetail';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

class WeatherForecast extends React.Component{
.
.
.
render(){
     return(
         <Router>
             <div className="weather-forecast">
                 <Nav value={"Weather Forecast"} />
                 <Switch>
                 <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <WeatherDisplay {...props}   reports={this.state.reports} /> }  />
                 <Route path="/:name-of-day" component={WeatherDetail} />
                 </Switch>
             </div>  
         </Router>   
     );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<WeatherForecast />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The WeatherDetail component

```
const WeatherDetail = () => (
     <div>
         <h1> More Information</h1>
     </div>
);

export default WeatherDetail;
```

Path Specification

```
<Link to={`/${handleDay(report.dt)}`}>
                    <li key={report.dt} className="weather-item">
                        <Day day={handleDay(report.dt)} />
                        <Icon icon={report.weather[0].icon} />
                        <TempMax temp={report.main.temp_max} />
                        <TempMin temp={report.main.temp_min} />
                        <div className="text-cont">
                            <div className="text"> click for more </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </Link>
```

when a weather-item is clicked, the weatherDetail component is expected to display but nothing displays and i get no errors. pls what am i doing wrong and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is likely with this line:

```
<Route path="/:name-of-day" component={WeatherDetail} />
```

`name-of-day` is actually a variable that's available on child components through `props.match`. I would rewrite it to be camel case like `nameOfDay`. Changing it to camelcase should solve your issues.

```
<Route path="/:nameOfDay" component={WeatherDetail} />
```